# Site only working in browser where I created it

Tags: images, themes

I built a site. I used Google Chrome to do it. Everything works properly in Google Chrome [only on this computer]. (logged in to wp-admin, and out too)
But...
The site does't work in any other browsers or computers. None of them (I tried IE, Edge, Opera, Safari [ios]).
The site loads, but none of the images, backgrounds load. Just as if they don't exist.
(In Edge I logged in to admin site to see that the pictures in media library apperas or not => but they were there!)

I tried close all the plugins, but that didn't works.

Any ideas? (I never met the same problem before)

Thanks

Comment: When you say that the site doesn't work, that could mean a lot of wildly different things, can you be more specific? If this is a frontend styling issue then you should ask on StackOverflow, generic CSS/JS issues aren't appropriate for this stack, and would be better asked on Stack Overflow. Otherwise there's very little information in your question, please edit it using the edit link to make it clearer and add a lot more information

Answer (score 0):

It could also be the site URL and Home settings in your database.  They might be 'localhost' or another URL only accessible in that browser.  If it's that, you'll need to change the values for the 'home' and 'siteurl' options in your database.  There's a few ways shown [here](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/change-wordpress-url/).

It's also possible, but less likely you are using Chrome's file override features: [Here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools)